# echarts map not displaying with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, echarts

please help because i'm stuck ,it's my first Laravel project using laravel 5.6 and i'm trying to use [echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) to generate [this example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=map-world-dataRange) but the map chart never render and no error at console.
my page.blade.php code :

```
    @extends('layouts.main')

@section('specialJS')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/charts/echarts-en.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/charts/crew_geo.js') }}"></script>
@endsection


@section('content')

    <div class="offset-md-2 mt-4">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="main" class="col-md-12 chart" style="height:400px;"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

note : specialJS section location at footer
and crew_geo.js :

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
    title : {
        text: 'World Population (2010)',
        subtext: 'from United Nations, Total population, both sexes combined, as of 1 July (thousands)',
        sublink : 'http://esa.un.org/wpp/Excel-Data/population.htm',
        left: 'center',
        top: 'top'
    },
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter : function (params) {
            var value = (params.value + '').split('.');
            value = value[0].replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
                    + '.' + value[1];
            return params.seriesName + '<br/>' + params.name + ' : ' + value;
        }
    },
    toolbox: {
        show : true,
        orient : 'vertical',
        left: 'right',
        top: 'center',
        feature : {
            mark : {show: true},
            dataView : {show: true, readOnly: false},
            restore : {show: true},
            saveAsImage : {show: true}
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        type: 'continuous',
        min: 0,
        max: 1000000,
        text:['High','Low'],
        realtime: false,
        calculable : true,
        color: ['orangered','yellow','lightskyblue']
    },
    series : [
        {
            name: 'World Population (2010)',
            type: 'map',
            mapType: 'world',
            roam: true,
            itemStyle:{
                emphasis:{label:{show:true}}
            },
            data:[
                {name : 'Afghanistan', value : 28397.812},
                {name : 'Angola', value : 19549.124},
                {name : 'Albania', value : 3150.143},
                {name : 'United Arab Emirates', value : 8441.537},
                {name : 'Argentina', value : 40374.224},
                {name : 'Armenia', value : 2963.496},
                {name : 'French Southern and Antarctic Lands', value : 268.065},
                {name : 'Australia', value : 22404.488},
                {name : 'Austria', value : 8401.924},
                {name : 'Azerbaijan', value : 9094.718},
                {name : 'Burundi', value : 9232.753},
                {name : 'Belgium', value : 10941.288},
                {name : 'Benin', value : 9509.798},
                {name : 'Burkina Faso', value : 15540.284},
                {name : 'Bangladesh', value : 151125.475},
                {name : 'Bulgaria', value : 7389.175},
                {name : 'The Bahamas', value : 66402.316},
                {name : 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', value : 3845.929},
                {name : 'Belarus', value : 9491.07},
                {name : 'Belize', value : 308.595},
                {name : 'Bermuda', value : 64.951},
                {name : 'Bolivia', value : 716.939},
                {name : 'Brazil', value : 195210.154},
                {name : 'Brunei', value : 27.223},
                {name : 'Bhutan', value : 716.939},
                {name : 'Botswana', value : 1969.341},
                {name : 'Central African Republic', value : 4349.921},
                {name : 'Canada', value : 34126.24},
                {name : 'Switzerland', value : 7830.534},
                {name : 'Chile', value : 17150.76},
                {name : 'China', value : 1359821.465},
                {name : 'Ivory Coast', value : 60508.978},
                {name : 'Cameroon', value : 20624.343},
                {name : 'Democratic Republic of the Congo', value : 62191.161},
                {name : 'Republic of the Congo', value : 3573.024},
                {name : 'Colombia', value : 46444.798},
                {name : 'Costa Rica', value : 4669.685},
                {name : 'Cuba', value : 11281.768},
                {name : 'Northern Cyprus', value : 1.468},
                {name : 'Cyprus', value : 1103.685},
                {name : 'Czech Republic', value : 10553.701},
                {name : 'Germany', value : 83017.404},
                {name : 'Djibouti', value : 834.036},
                {name : 'Denmark', value : 5550.959},
                {name : 'Dominican Republic', value : 10016.797},
                {name : 'Algeria', value : 37062.82},
                {name : 'Ecuador', value : 15001.072},
                {name : 'Egypt', value : 78075.705},
                {name : 'Eritrea', value : 5741.159},
                {name : 'Spain', value : 46182.038},
                {name : 'Estonia', value : 1298.533},
                {name : 'Ethiopia', value : 87095.281},
                {name : 'Finland', value : 5367.693},
                {name : 'Fiji', value : 860.559},
                {name : 'Falkland Islands', value : 49.581},
                {name : 'France', value : 63230.866},
                {name : 'Gabon', value : 1556.222},
                {name : 'United Kingdom', value : 62066.35},
                {name : 'Georgia', value : 4388.674},
                {name : 'Ghana', value : 24262.901},
                {name : 'Guinea', value : 10876.033},
                {name : 'Gambia', value : 1680.64},
                {name : 'Guinea Bissau', value : 10876.033},
                {name : 'Equatorial Guinea', value : 696.167},
                {name : 'Greece', value : 11109.999},
                {name : 'Greenland', value : 56.546},
                {name : 'Guatemala', value : 14341.576},
                {name : 'French Guiana', value : 231.169},
                {name : 'Guyana', value : 786.126},
                {name : 'Honduras', value : 7621.204},
                {name : 'Croatia', value : 4338.027},
                {name : 'Haiti', value : 9896.4},
                {name : 'Hungary', value : 10014.633},
                {name : 'Indonesia', value : 240676.485},
                {name : 'India', value : 1205624.648},
                {name : 'Ireland', value : 4467.561},
                {name : 'Iran', value : 240676.485},
                {name : 'Iraq', value : 30962.38},
                {name : 'Iceland', value : 318.042},
                {name : 'Israel', value : 7420.368},
                {name : 'Italy', value : 60508.978},
                {name : 'Jamaica', value : 2741.485},
                {name : 'Jordan', value : 6454.554},
                {name : 'Japan', value : 127352.833},
                {name : 'Kazakhstan', value : 15921.127},
                {name : 'Kenya', value : 40909.194},
                {name : 'Kyrgyzstan', value : 5334.223},
                {name : 'Cambodia', value : 14364.931},
                {name : 'South Korea', value : 51452.352},
                {name : 'Kosovo', value : 97.743},
                {name : 'Kuwait', value : 2991.58},
                {name : 'Laos', value : 6395.713},
                {name : 'Lebanon', value : 4341.092},
                {name : 'Liberia', value : 3957.99},
                {name : 'Libya', value : 6040.612},
                {name : 'Sri Lanka', value : 20758.779},
                {name : 'Lesotho', value : 2008.921},
                {name : 'Lithuania', value : 3068.457},
                {name : 'Luxembourg', value : 507.885},
                {name : 'Latvia', value : 2090.519},
                {name : 'Morocco', value : 31642.36},
                {name : 'Moldova', value : 103.619},
                {name : 'Madagascar', value : 21079.532},
                {name : 'Mexico', value : 117886.404},
                {name : 'Macedonia', value : 507.885},
                {name : 'Mali', value : 13985.961},
                {name : 'Myanmar', value : 51931.231},
                {name : 'Montenegro', value : 620.078},
                {name : 'Mongolia', value : 2712.738},
                {name : 'Mozambique', value : 23967.265},
                {name : 'Mauritania', value : 3609.42},
                {name : 'Malawi', value : 15013.694},
                {name : 'Malaysia', value : 28275.835},
                {name : 'Namibia', value : 2178.967},
                {name : 'New Caledonia', value : 246.379},
                {name : 'Niger', value : 15893.746},
                {name : 'Nigeria', value : 159707.78},
                {name : 'Nicaragua', value : 5822.209},
                {name : 'Netherlands', value : 16615.243},
                {name : 'Norway', value : 4891.251},
                {name : 'Nepal', value : 26846.016},
                {name : 'New Zealand', value : 4368.136},
                {name : 'Oman', value : 2802.768},
                {name : 'Pakistan', value : 173149.306},
                {name : 'Panama', value : 3678.128},
                {name : 'Peru', value : 29262.83},
                {name : 'Philippines', value : 93444.322},
                {name : 'Papua New Guinea', value : 6858.945},
                {name : 'Poland', value : 38198.754},
                {name : 'Puerto Rico', value : 3709.671},
                {name : 'North Korea', value : 1.468},
                {name : 'Portugal', value : 10589.792},
                {name : 'Paraguay', value : 6459.721},
                {name : 'Qatar', value : 1749.713},
                {name : 'Romania', value : 21861.476},
                {name : 'Russia', value : 21861.476},
                {name : 'Rwanda', value : 10836.732},
                {name : 'Western Sahara', value : 514.648},
                {name : 'Saudi Arabia', value : 27258.387},
                {name : 'Sudan', value : 35652.002},
                {name : 'South Sudan', value : 9940.929},
                {name : 'Senegal', value : 12950.564},
                {name : 'Solomon Islands', value : 526.447},
                {name : 'Sierra Leone', value : 5751.976},
                {name : 'El Salvador', value : 6218.195},
                {name : 'Somaliland', value : 9636.173},
                {name : 'Somalia', value : 9636.173},
                {name : 'Republic of Serbia', value : 3573.024},
                {name : 'Suriname', value : 524.96},
                {name : 'Slovakia', value : 5433.437},
                {name : 'Slovenia', value : 2054.232},
                {name : 'Sweden', value : 9382.297},
                {name : 'Swaziland', value : 1193.148},
                {name : 'Syria', value : 7830.534},
                {name : 'Chad', value : 11720.781},
                {name : 'Togo', value : 6306.014},
                {name : 'Thailand', value : 66402.316},
                {name : 'Tajikistan', value : 7627.326},
                {name : 'Turkmenistan', value : 5041.995},
                {name : 'East Timor', value : 10016.797},
                {name : 'Trinidad and Tobago', value : 1328.095},
                {name : 'Tunisia', value : 10631.83},
                {name : 'Turkey', value : 72137.546},
                {name : 'United Republic of Tanzania', value : 44973.33},
                {name : 'Uganda', value : 33987.213},
                {name : 'Ukraine', value : 46050.22},
                {name : 'Uruguay', value : 3371.982},
                {name : 'United States of America', value : 312247.116},
                {name : 'Uzbekistan', value : 27769.27},
                {name : 'Venezuela', value : 236.299},
                {name : 'Vietnam', value : 89047.397},
                {name : 'Vanuatu', value : 236.299},
                {name : 'West Bank', value : 13.565},
                {name : 'Yemen', value : 22763.008},
                {name : 'South Africa', value : 51452.352},
                {name : 'Zambia', value : 13216.985},
                {name : 'Zimbabwe', value : 13076.978}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
myChart.setOption(option);
```

i don't know whats wrong but this code only display :

[image: this only displayed with no error at console or laravel errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using echarts, installed through npm in Quasar/Vue/Nodejs, we had to register the map json file for the chart against a name ('world' in this case) to get rid of the missing map error.
Laravel would probably require something similar to:

```
echarts.registerMap('world',require('echarts/map/json/world.json'));
this.chart = echarts.init(this.$refs.chart);
```

Comment: thanks , as u mentioned i must register map itself ,but what i found that the PHP version from here https://github.com/hisune/Echarts-PHP  is more friendly to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

i found that to use [PHP version of echarts](https://github.com/hisune/Echarts-PHP) is more friendly with Laravel,so here is the steps :

1- in your model make chart function like :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use \Hisune\EchartsPHP\ECharts;
use \Hisune\EchartsPHP\Doc\IDE\Series;
use Hisune\EchartsPHP\Config;

class User extends Authenticatable{

  public function nationality_geo(){

    $nationality_array=user::all('nationality')->unique('nationality');

    $countries=array(
        "AF"=>"Afghan","AX"=>"\u00c5land Island","AL"=>"Albanian","DZ"=>"Algerian","AS"=>"American Samoan","AD"=>"Andorran","AO"=>"Angolan","AI"=>"Anguillan","AQ"=>"Antarctic","AG"=>"Antiguan or Barbudan","AR"=>"Argentine","AM"=>"Armenian","AW"=>"Aruban","AU"=>"Australian","AT"=>"Austrian","AZ"=>"Azerbaijani, Azeri","BS"=>"Bahamian","BH"=>"Bahraini","BD"=>"Bangladeshi","BB"=>"Barbadian","BY"=>"Belarusian","BE"=>"Belgian","BZ"=>"Belizean","BJ"=>"Beninese, Beninois","BM"=>"Bermudian, Bermudan","BT"=>"Bhutanese","BO"=>"Bolivian","BQ"=>"Bonaire","BA"=>"Bosnian or Herzegovinian","BW"=>"Motswana, Botswanan","BV"=>"Bouvet Island","BR"=>"Brazilian","IO"=>"BIOT","BN"=>"Bruneian","BG"=>"Bulgarian","BF"=>"Burkinab\u00e9","BI"=>"Burundian","CV"=>"Cabo Verdean","KH"=>"Cambodian","CM"=>"Cameroonian","CA"=>"Canadian","KY"=>"Caymanian","CF"=>"Central African","TD"=>"Chadian","CL"=>"Chilean","CN"=>"Chinese","CX"=>"Christmas Island","CC"=>"Cocos Island","CO"=>"Colombian","KM"=>"Comoran, Comorian","CG"=>"Congolese","CD"=>"Congolese","CK"=>"Cook Island","CR"=>"Costa Rican","CI"=>"Ivorian","HR"=>"Croatian","CU"=>"Cuban","CW"=>"Cura\u00e7aoan","CY"=>"Cypriot","CZ"=>"Czech","DK"=>"Danish","DJ"=>"Djiboutian","DM"=>"Dominican","DO"=>"Dominican","EC"=>"Ecuadorian","EG"=>"Egyptian","SV"=>"Salvadoran","GQ"=>"Equatorial Guinean, Equatoguinean","ER"=>"Eritrean","EE"=>"Estonian","ET"=>"Ethiopian","FK"=>"Falkland Island","FO"=>"Faroese","FJ"=>"Fijian","FI"=>"Finnish","FR"=>"French","GF"=>"French Guianese","PF"=>"French Polynesian","TF"=>"French Southern Territories","GA"=>"Gabonese","GM"=>"Gambian","GE"=>"Georgian","DE"=>"German","GH"=>"Ghanaian","GI"=>"Gibraltar","GR"=>"Greek, Hellenic","GL"=>"Greenlandic","GD"=>"Grenadian","GP"=>"Guadeloupe","GU"=>"Guamanian, Guambat","GT"=>"Guatemalan","GG"=>"Channel Island","GN"=>"Guinean","GW"=>"Bissau-Guinean","GY"=>"Guyanese","HT"=>"Haitian","HM"=>"Heard Island or McDonald Islands","VA"=>"Vatican","HN"=>"Honduran","HK"=>"Hong Kong, Hong Kongese","HU"=>"Hungarian, Magyar","IS"=>"Icelandic","IN"=>"Indian","ID"=>"Indonesian","IR"=>"Iranian, Persian","IQ"=>"Iraqi","IE"=>"Irish","IM"=>"Manx","IL"=>"Israeli","IT"=>"Italian","JM"=>"Jamaican","JP"=>"Japanese","JE"=>"Channel Island","JO"=>"Jordanian","KZ"=>"Kazakhstani, Kazakh","KE"=>"Kenyan","KI"=>"I-Kiribati","KP"=>"North Korean","KR"=>"South Korean","KW"=>"Kuwaiti","KG"=>"Kyrgyzstani, Kyrgyz, Kirgiz, Kirghiz","LA"=>"Lao, Laotian","LV"=>"Latvian","LB"=>"Lebanese","LS"=>"Basotho","LR"=>"Liberian","LY"=>"Libyan","LI"=>"Liechtenstein","LT"=>"Lithuanian","LU"=>"Luxembourg, Luxembourgish","MO"=>"Macanese, Chinese","MK"=>"Macedonian","MG"=>"Malagasy","MW"=>"Malawian","MY"=>"Malaysian","MV"=>"Maldivian","ML"=>"Malian, Malinese","MT"=>"Maltese","MH"=>"Marshallese","MQ"=>"Martiniquais, Martinican","MR"=>"Mauritanian","MU"=>"Mauritian","YT"=>"Mahoran","MX"=>"Mexican","FM"=>"Micronesian","MD"=>"Moldovan","MC"=>"Mon\u00e9gasque, Monacan","MN"=>"Mongolian","ME"=>"Montenegrin","MS"=>"Montserratian","MA"=>"Moroccan","MZ"=>"Mozambican","MM"=>"Burmese","NA"=>"Namibian","NR"=>"Nauruan","NP"=>"Nepali, Nepalese","NL"=>"Dutch, Netherlandic","NC"=>"New Caledonian","NZ"=>"New Zealand, NZ","NI"=>"Nicaraguan","NE"=>"Nigerien","NG"=>"Nigerian","NU"=>"Niuean","NF"=>"Norfolk Island","MP"=>"Northern Marianan","NO"=>"Norwegian","OM"=>"Omani","PK"=>"Pakistani","PW"=>"Palauan","PS"=>"Palestinian","PA"=>"Panamanian","PG"=>"Papua New Guinean, Papuan","PY"=>"Paraguayan","PE"=>"Peruvian","PH"=>"Philippine, Filipino","PN"=>"Pitcairn Island","PL"=>"Polish","PT"=>"Portuguese","PR"=>"Puerto Rican","QA"=>"Qatari","RE"=>"R\u00e9unionese, R\u00e9unionnais","RO"=>"Romanian","RU"=>"Russian","RW"=>"Rwandan","BL"=>"Barth\u00e9lemois","SH"=>"Saint Helenian","KN"=>"Kittitian or Nevisian","LC"=>"Saint Lucian","MF"=>"Saint-Martinoise","PM"=>"Saint-Pierrais or Miquelonnais","VC"=>"Saint Vincentian, Vincentian","WS"=>"Samoan","SM"=>"Sammarinese","ST"=>"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9an","SA"=>"Saudi Arabian","SN"=>"Senegalese","RS"=>"Serbian","SC"=>"Seychellois","SL"=>"Sierra Leonean","SG"=>"Singaporean","SX"=>"Sint Maarten","SK"=>"Slovak","SI"=>"Slovenian, Slovene","SB"=>"Solomon Island","SO"=>"Somali, Somalian","ZA"=>"South African","GS"=>"South Georgia or South Sandwich Islands","SS"=>"South Sudanese","ES"=>"Spanish","LK"=>"Sri Lankan","SD"=>"Sudanese","SR"=>"Surinamese","SJ"=>"Svalbard","SZ"=>"Swazi","SE"=>"Swedish","CH"=>"Swiss","SY"=>"Syrian","TW"=>"Chinese, Taiwanese","TJ"=>"Tajikistani","TZ"=>"Tanzanian","TH"=>"Thai","TL"=>"Timorese","TG"=>"Togolese","TK"=>"Tokelauan","TO"=>"Tongan","TT"=>"Trinidadian or Tobagonian","TN"=>"Tunisian","TR"=>"Turkish","TM"=>"Turkmen","TC"=>"Turks and Caicos Island","TV"=>"Tuvaluan","UG"=>"Ugandan","UA"=>"Ukrainian","AE"=>"Emirati, Emirian, Emiri","GB"=>"British, UK","UM"=>"American","US"=>"American","UY"=>"Uruguayan","UZ"=>"Uzbekistani, Uzbek","VU"=>"Ni-Vanuatu, Vanuatuan","VE"=>"Venezuelan","VN"=>"Vietnamese","VG"=>"British Virgin Island","VI"=>"U.S. Virgin Island","WF"=>"Wallis and Futuna, Wallisian or Futunan","EH"=>"Sahrawi, Sahrawian, Sahraouian","YE"=>"Yemeni","ZM"=>"Zambian","ZW"=>"Zimbabwean"
    ); 

    foreach ($nationality_array as $nationality_data) { 

        $country_code=array_search($nationality_data->nationality,$countries,false);

        $nationalitys[]=[
            'value' => user::all()->where('nationality',$nationality_data->nationality)->count(),
            'name'  => $country_code
        ];

    }

    $chart = new ECharts();
    $chart->visualMap->min = 0;
    $chart->visualMap->max = 100;
    $chart->visualMap->text = ['High', 'Low'];
    $chart->visualMap->calculable = true;
    $chart->visualMap->inRange->color = ['#20c997', '#dc3545'];
    $chart->tooltip->trigger = 'item';
    $chart->tooltip->formatter = '{a} {b} {c}';
    $chart->title->text='Employee Nationality Distribution';
    $chart->title->textStyle->color='#17a2b8';

    $chart->title->left='center';
    $chart->title->top='top';

    $chart->toolbox->show=true;
    $chart->toolbox->orient='vertical';
    $chart->toolbox->left='right';
    $chart->toolbox->top='center';

    $chart->toolbox->feature->mark->show=true;

    $chart->toolbox->feature->restore->show=true;
    $chart->toolbox->feature->restore->title='Restore';

    $chart->toolbox->feature->saveAsImage->show=true;
    $chart->toolbox->feature->saveAsImage->title='Save';

    $series = new Series();
    $series->name = 'From ';
    $series->type = 'map';
    $series->map = 'world';
    $series->nameMap = \Hisune\EchartsPHP\Countries::nameMap();
    $series->data = $nationalitys;
    $series->label->emphasis->show = true;
    $series->label->emphasis->textStyle->color = '#fff';

    $series->roam = true;
    $series->scaleLimit->min = 1;
    $series->scaleLimit->max = 5;

    $series->itemStyle->normal->borderColor = '#bbb';
    $series->itemStyle->normal->areaColor = '#F5F6FA';
    $series->itemStyle->emphasis->areaColor = '#441744';

    $chart->addSeries($series);
//refer to world map :

Config::addExtraScript('world.js', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/hisune/images/7b31b0a0/echarts');

    return $chart->render('map');    

}

}
```

2-then in your blade call it like that :

```
                    {!! Auth::user()->nationality_geo() !!}
```